# SQL identifying where the previous row number contained xyz

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, case

I wanted to know how I can make a query in SQL where I have pulled out some data and given row_numbers (partitioned by a trade id) and when I pull a item that has the specific action 'AMEND' done on it (e.g. if row 2 record had the AMEND action) then I want to see what the row 3 action was.

If row 3 action was 'UPDATE' then I want a new field to say 'REMOVE' on both and if there was either no row 3 for that trade or row 3 action was not UPDATE then I want the new field to say 'KEEP'

Is this easily done?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give the schema or sample of the data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to self-reference that table so you will be able to pull out the previus row data

```
with cte as( select *
, rownumber() over by (partition by trade_id order by......) as seq 
from table )
select * from cte t1 
left join cte t2 on t1.seq= t2.seq + 1
```

Lets say, your field names in cte are aliesed as A and B, since you have self referenced the table. Now insert the generated results into a temp  table.

Then, you can structure your CASE statement based on the ACTION from the previous row:

```
  select 
 a.action 
, case when (b.action= 'Update' and a.action= 'amend') then 'REmove'
  else 'keep'
  end NEWField
from #temp
```